# How to parse JSON object?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm try to get data from php web-service through the java-script.In my project error occurred when parse the JSON.

My PHP web service like this

```
<?php
header("Content-Type:application/json");

try {
    if(!empty($_POST['mobile_number']))
    {
        $number = $_POST['mobile_number'];
        $number = $_POST['user_type'];
        deliver_response(200, "success", $number);      
    }
    else 
    {
        deliver_response(400, "no parameter", $number);
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo("message".$e->getMessage());

}


function deliver_response($status,$status_message,$data)
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 $status $status_message");

    $response['status'] = $status;
    $response['status_message'] = $status_message;
    //$response['data'] = $data;

    $json_response = json_encode($response);
    echo $json_response;    
}
?>
```

And Im try to call above webservice like this

```
function logingAuth(){
    var mnumber= $("#uname").val();
    var utype= $("#pword").val();
    try{
    $.post("http://192.168.1.55/rest/signup.php", { mobile_number: mnumber,user_type:utype }, parseResults);
}
catch(err)
{
alert(err.message);
}
    function parseResults(json){
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
        alert(obj.status);
    }   
}
```

but this one not working because of var `obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json);` line.

If I call like this Its working

```
function parseResults(json){
        alert(json.status);

    }
```

What is this problem?

Comment: when u parseJSON, you are decode it into array. then you cant do the json.status

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery will automatically recognise the response type for you and act appropriately. In this case it will automatically deserialise the JSON to an object, so your call to `parseJSON` will cause an error as you are trying to deserialise an object. Simply remove that line:

```
function parseResults(json){
    alert(json.status);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.Actually I use  jQuery mobile.is that oky to implement without that line.

Comment: Thats fine, this is part of plain jQuery. jQM has no effect on this.